# Django nested serializer doesn't save as expected

Tags: python, django, serialization, django-rest-framework

I want to tag users in an image and save it, I used nested serializer since you can tag more than one user in an image.
The problem is that the image is saved without the tags(they are none).
Here is the codes:
models.py

```
class TagUsername(models.Model):
    # the tag is person
    tag = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='tag_username')
    image = models.ForeignKey(Image)

    # # De tection Rectangle specs(width,height, coordinate x & coordinate y)
    # width = models.FloatField()
    # length = models.FloatField()
    # xCoordinate = models.FloatField()
    # yCoordinate = models.FloatField()

    # who added this tag
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

serializers.py

```
class TagUsernameSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    tag = UsernameTagSerializer(read_only=True, many=True)
    user = serializers.SlugRelatedField(queryset=User.objects.all(), slug_field="username")
    image = serializers.CharField(source='image_id')

    class Meta:
        model = TagUsername
        fields = ('tag', 'user', 'image')
```

UsernameTagSerializer:

```
class UsernameTagSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    # username = serializers.SlugRelatedField(queryset=User.objects.all(), slug_field="username")

    class Meta:
        model = User
        # fields I want only
        fields = ('username', )
```

Any idea whats wrong !

Answer (score 1):

You need to override `create` method to save nested objects. Try this:

```
def create(self, validated_data):
    tag_username = super().create(validated_data)
    for tag in validated_data['tag']:
        user = User.objects.get(username=tag['username']
        tag_username.tag.add(user) 
    return tag_username
```

You can find more details about writable nested serialization in [docs](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#writable-nested-serializers).

Comment: the problem is tag is not in the validated_data ! only user and image are found.

Comment: @Engineer try to set tag source as `tag` or `tag_set`:  `tag = UsernameTagSerializer(source='tag', read_only=True, many=True)`